# VisualStudio 2010 Settings Page - Collection Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings.settings, application-settings

- I have a list of Filemaker database names
- Each DB name has a list of field/attribute pairs associated with it
- I have a windows form application in C# 4.0 (vs2010) that wants to use the above data
- I would like to maintain the list either in the Visual Studio settings page, or in one of the standard visual studio settings files using the standard .NET settings calls
- I would like to avoid writing my own custom settings, xml, xds (to avoid the "Could not    find schema information for the element/attribute " errors)
- I just have a slightly complicated INI file! I don't want to complicate my life!

Do any easy solutions exist?

Unless someone has a brighter idea, I am simply going to write string settings with names that indicate it's a FM DB (e.g. "fmdbAddresses"), and values that concat my field/attribute pairs (e.g. "gUserResult=skipField|gAddressID=convertToInt|gAddressID=uniqueIx")

Comment: A slight improvement - I can store lists thanks to this article: http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34273/1954 - in Settings Page, select System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection as the type, and then you can edit a string collection directly in the settings page.
Access the strings via the settings name, e.g. if your collection is called MyItems, then you access them via foreach (string str in Properties.Settings.Default.MyItems))
NOTE: I ran into the exception: 
The assembly with display name 'System.XmlSerializers' failed to load. Deleting the SOU file killed the exception.

Comment: The joke's on me - killing the SOU file only cleared my "break on exceptions" options. Exception still occurs. According to MS, this exception is "by design": https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=88566&wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I worked through the excellent articles by [Jon Rista](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx) on CodeProject, which led me to the "Could not find schema information for the element/attribute" errors. In any case, for the info that I wanted to store, I think an XML file, a specially built class needing to know a lot about VS config files, and an XDS file or include to bring one in is more than a bit overblown.

I also read and tried things from a few dozen pages on the web... I gained a deeper understanding of the .NET way, but still nothing which I found simple or elegant enough.

I find it hard to believe there is not a better way that I'm somehow missing.